# Prove that $\psi\in\operatorname{Aut}(Q_8)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $Q_8\le G$ where $G$ has an element of order $3$, call it $a$.

Let $\psi:Q_8\longrightarrow Q_8$ be defined by the conjugation by $a$, i.e. $\psi:q\mapsto q^a$.

Suppose to know that this is not a trivial map and that $(Q_8)^a=Q_8$.

I have to prove that $\psi\in\operatorname{Aut}(Q_8)$.

1. $\psi$ is easily a group omomorphism.
2. $\psi$ is not trivial and surjective (since $(Q_8)^a=Q_8$) by the hypotesis.
3. $\ker\psi=C_{Q_8}(a)$ but I'm not able to show that it's trivial. It should, but seeing $Q_8$ as a set of square matrixes of order $2$, we note that $Z(Q_8)=\{\pm\mathbb I\}$ from which $\psi$ wouldn't be injective.

Where is the problem in the third point?

Thank you all

Comment: It is not always helpful to have unnecessary information. For any subgroup $H \le G$ and any $a \in G$ with $H^a=H$, the map $\psi:H\to H$ with $\psi(h)=h^a$ is an automorphism of $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel is not center in that case,

remember that $$ker=\{x\in Q_8 | x^a=e\}$$

But if $x^a=e$ then $x=e$.

I think you are confusing the terms fixing the elements and sendinig the elements to identity.

Comment: clear, thanks and sorry for the stupid question

Comment: you are welcome, I do not think it is a stupid question, at the begining of group theory, concepts may be confusings as they are resemle to each other.